# How do I change the RoR Active Admin filter button text to English

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm not sure where the js code is that creates the button

[image]

I've inspected the JS source and searched for the filter text and found it coming from here:

[image]

Comment: Check in your `config/locale/en.yml` config.

Comment: @tadman Nothing in there other than 'en:  hello: "Hello world"'

Comment: Not worked on active admin. The text seems french. Check `config/locale/fr.yml`. It might be possible this file comes from other gem.